# How can we synchronize the NAO robots?

Tags: synchronization, nao-robot

I am setting up my NAO robots for a dance sequence using programming in Python, so how to make sure that robots always stay in synchronizationLik?

How will I handle the situation where one robot falls and now I have to make it sync with other robots?

I am able to start the robots at the same time, I am using the Choreographe software to handle the dance moves and trigger the robots using their IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have the robot synchronized on the same NTP server.
2. Let your program decide of the time at which the dance starts, so that you can always know where you are supposed to be at in the dance.
3. Normally it should stay synchronized, but if a desynchronization appears, you can request the timeline to go to the desired frame regularly, with some Python code on the timeline box, using the [`goTo(int)`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/software/choregraphe/objects/python_script.html#timeline) function.
4. If a robot falls, `pause()` the timeline, get the robot up, then `goto(int)` the desired frame and then `play()` the timeline.

Comment: I want the robot to interact with other robots as well; the fallen robot should stand and go to the frame number that is the average of all other robots dancing currently. I have implemented the code in timeline box using **goTo()** function but how do we access the timeline from other code that used to trigger the NAO robots, not from timeline box?

Comment: Sorry but this is a separate question, and you do not need that. Tracking the current frame from remote for every robot involves latency that makes it harder to achieve the synchronization. The best is that it relies on a clock, which is accessed immediately by the system. If you still want to have remote calls, you can still publish the average current frame in several ways, with `ALMemory` for example.